# Oracle PLSQL refcursor%ROWTYPE the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to assign cursor variable in PL/SQL code and then fetch a row from that. When I declared cursor explicitly, it works.

```
DECLARE
cursor c1 is SELECT * from acme;
row1 c1%ROWTYPE;
```

but when I use code to assign cursor per e.g. [Oracle PLSQL setting a cursor from a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346717/oracle-plsql-setting-a-cursor-from-a-variable) like that:

```
  c1 sys_refcursor;
  r1 c1%ROWTYPE;
```

I get error

> the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or
>   malformed

writting just `r1 %ROWTYPE` produces error too.

As per general use of variables explained e.g. here [How to declare variable and use it in the same Oracle SQL script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564283/how-to-declare-variable-and-use-it-in-the-same-oracle-sql-script) I've tried:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  c1 sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
    open c1 for 'SELECT * FROM foo';
    declare r1 c1%ROWTYPE;
    begin
        fetch c1 into r1; 
    end;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('FOO');    
    close c1;
END;
```

and again got `the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed`

How can I declare variable of row type it my case? Oracle 11g.
P.S. workaround would be to `fetch c1 into v_empno, v_ename, ect` declaring several variables, still, is there a way to use rowtype one?

Comment: Short answer - a `sys_refcursor` doesn't have any columns defined so it has no `%rowtype`, and neither does a dynamic ref cursor at compile time.

Comment: @William Robertson, thank you. I've implemented sort of workaround as my queries are different still sililar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    c1 sys_refcursor;
  3    r1 dept%rowtype;                      --> this
  4  begin
  5    open c1 for 'select * from dept';
  6    fetch c1 into r1;
  7    dbms_output.put_line(r1.dname);
  8  end;
  9  /
ACCOUNTING

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: the reason I want to use refcursor variable is that I assign different selects to it in a loop, selects using joins and external database links.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can't do that; you'll have to fetch each ref cursor's column into its own variable.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to display result from any given query, you may use this standard procedure similar to the one described in [this AskTOM article](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:9537323500346032880)

```
create or replace procedure return_result( l_query varchar2 )
   is
       l_theCursor     integer default dbms_sql.open_cursor;
       l_columnValue   varchar2(4000);
       l_status        integer;
       l_colCnt        number := 0;
       l_separator     varchar2(1);
       l_descTbl       dbms_sql.desc_tab;
   begin
       dbms_sql.parse(  l_theCursor,  l_query, dbms_sql.native );

       dbms_sql.describe_columns( l_theCursor, l_colCnt, l_descTbl );


           l_separator := '';
           for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop
               dbms_output.put( l_separator || l_descTbl(i).col_name );
               l_separator := ',';
           end loop;
           dbms_output.put_line('');

        for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop
           dbms_sql.define_column( l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue, 4000 );
       end loop;
       l_status := dbms_sql.execute(l_theCursor);

       while ( dbms_sql.fetch_rows(l_theCursor) > 0 ) loop
           l_separator := '';
           for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop
               dbms_sql.column_value( l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue );
               dbms_output.put( l_separator || l_columnValue );
               l_separator := ',';
           end loop;
           dbms_output.new_line;
       end loop;
       dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_theCursor);
   end;
 /
```

Pass any query to this procedure to get result.

```
set serveroutput on
set feedback off
set sqlformat ansiconsole
set pages 0
BEGIN
return_result('select e.employee_id,e.first_name,e.salary,
          d.department_name from 
          employees e join 
  departments d on e.department_id= d.department_id');
END;
/
```

Result

```
EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,SALARY,DEPARTMENT_NAME
200,Jennifer,4400,Administration
201,Michael,13000,Marketing
202,Pat,6000,Marketing
114,Den,11000,Purchasing
```

**Note**: Oracle 12c provides `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT` using which this procedure can be easily implemented.